# Is reading a romantic fanfiction considered zina?

Tags: halal-haram, zina

Is it considered zina if you fantasized or imagined being in a relationship even though you did not act upon it?

Comment: Let me ask you this. Are you murder for killing people in video games? Think about this question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first tell you the difination of zina : Zina is an Islamic legal term referring to unlawful **sexual intercourse**. This is the difination of zina.

Do not go near adultery. It is truly a shameful deed and an evil way.
Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran 17:32
Even if you think of zina it is not zina in actual, but it is a sin that to when you are thinking about the lewd and dirty things. But romantic novels do not have such thing (at least the one I know) so you can read it. Read romantic novel is not a sin but if it contains dirty and adult line that is very sexual, then it is sin. Otherwise not.

Answer (score -1):

I think someone said this but, if you kill someone in a video game are you a murderer no! So weather it's novels or webtoons if its does not make you want to do zina or a sin it's absolutely okay to read/watch them. I hope i helped have a great day